# How to persist selection of GTK_THEME in running applications in Xfce?

Tags: debian, themes, xfce, gtk

I'm running Xfce on Debian.  The menu labels in many windows look crowded and some dialogue controls are missing.  The work-around I have found (I cannot remember how) is to prefix a application's start-up command with

```
GTK_THEME=/usr/share/themes/Xfce-4.6/gtk-3.0/gtk.css
```

For example, let's say I would like to adjust the volume.  In the top-right of the desktop, next to the clock is an icon that looks like a speaker.

Click on that icon and a menu drops down.  Move the mouse pointer up and down over the menu items and already something looks peculiar.  Each menu-item has to the left of it (ie, between the left-most edge of the menu and the left-most letter in the menu-item's label) some grey space.  You might say the menu items are indented.  Hover the mouse pointer over a menu-item and that grey space to the left it becomes . . . brighter.

Click on one of the menu-items, **Audio mixer...**

A window opens, all grey with **Volume Control** in the title bar.  This window, too, looks odd.  Starting from the left, across the top, are a string of letters

**PlaybackRecordingOutput DevicesInput DevicesConfiguration**

Lower down, seemingly floating in space, the word **Advanced**.  Hover your mouse pointer over the word **Advanced** and its background becomes brighter.  Click on it and a row of words appears below.

See the problem?  I didn't at first.

Now apply the work-around.

Close the window by clicking the **X** at the far-right end of the title bar, open a command prompt and enter

```
GTK_THEME=/usr/share/themes/Xfce-4.6/gtk-3.0/gtk.css pavucontrol
```

A window opens, the same size as the other and also with **Volume Control** in the title bar.  But this not grey.  It's almost entirely white.  Across the top is not a string letters but a row of tabs the labels of which are separated by significant amount of space.

**Playback**   **Recording**   **Output Devices**   **Input Devices**   **Confiugration**

The word **Advanced** is there as before, but now with a little triangle to the left of it, pointing at it.  Click on the word and the triangle turns and points downwards.

So instead of clicking on the volume icon, I must instead always use this `GTK_THEME` command.

```
GTK_THEME=/usr/share/themes/Xfce-4.6/gtk-3.0/gtk.css pavucontrol
```

I have tried changing the *style*.  Ie, **Applications** in the top-left of the desktop > **Settings** > **Settings Manager** > **Appearance**.

A window with four tabs opens: **Style**, **Icons**, **Fonts**, **Settings**,  I've tried all the different *styles*.  Each gives me different colours in the title bars and the like.  None renders the menu- or tab-labels properly as does the `GTK_THEME` command.

Another example is vinagre.  I am left to do a lot of guessing as to where to click if I run just

```
vinagre
```

or open it from **Applications** > **Internet** > **Remote Desktop Viewer**

but if I run it with

```
GTK_THEME=/usr/share/themes/Xfce-4.6/gtk-3.0/gtk.css vinagre
```

all kinds of hitherto invisible buttons appear.

Upon exiting, though, I notice in the command prompt a bunch of innocuous warnings such as

```
(vinagre:6118): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: :6:27: The style property GtkWidget:focus-padding is deprecated and shouldn't be used anymore. It will be removed in a future version
```

or

```
(vinagre:6118): Gtk-WARNING **: Drawing a gadget with negative dimensions. Did you forget to allocate a size? (node box owner ViewAutoDrawer)
```

have appeared in the command prompt window.

I have read at //wiki.xfce.org/howto/install_new_themes that, for "GTK+ interfaces" (perhaps pavucontrol is a GTK+ interface), can can "Extract the theme in `~/.local/share/themes`"  I don't have a `themes` directory in my `~/.local/share` directory . . . is that not part of a standard Xfce installation?

Is there a way that I can specify that call programs should be run with

```
GTK_THEME=/usr/share/themes/Xfce-4.6/gtk-3.0/gtk.css
```

without having to install a new *theme* ?

Opening the **Applications** menu from the top-left corner of the desktop and selecting **About Xfce** reveals that I'm using version 4.12 of Xfce.

Answer (score 0):

Found this forum discussion https://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?id=6263 where mmassonnet suggested on 2011-09-03:

> install Greybird, it has support for GTK2 and GTK3 theming.
>   http://shimmerproject.org/project/greybird/

So I opened up Synaptic.

```
$ su - root
```

```
# GTK_THEME=/usr/share/themes/Xfce-4.6/gtk-3.0/gtk.css synaptic
```

therein searched for `greybird` and found and installed (along with all dependencies) a package named **greybird-gtk-theme**.

Once that was installed, I went back to **Applications** (in the top-left corner of the desktop) > **Settings** > **Settings Manager** > **Appearence**.  On the **Style** tab, a bunch of new *styles* including (to name a few): **Blackbird**, **Bluebird**, **Greybird**, **Kiwi**, **MurrinaAqualsh**, **MurrinaBlau**, **MurrinaBlu**, etc.

I arbitrarily picked **MurrinaBlu** and closed the **Appearance** window.

After a few seconds, it looked better. Opening the volume-icon's menu (in the top-right of the desktop), the same list of menu-items appeared.  But now to the left of **Mute audio output**, instead of empty grey space, is a check box. Clicking on **Audio mixer...** opens a window much like the one I had with

```
$ GTK_THEME=/usr/share/themes/Xfce-4.6/gtk-3.0/gtk.css pavucontrol
```

So looks like the problem is solved.  Thanks, mmassonnet.